# alternative for mongoose-xray for mongoose version 6.x

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, npm, mongoose, aws-xray

I have been using mongoose-xray as a plugin to mongoose 5.x to log requests and subsegments through AWSXray.

Nevertheless I now want to update mongodb from version 4.4 to version 5.x which implies to update mongoose to version 6.x.

mongoose-xray is incompatible with mongoose 6.x and I have been unsuccessfully looking for alternative. Do you know if I missed something? is a compatible version of mongoose-xray planned?